# Extracting a list of tuples from a list of dictionaries, some values separated with commas and single quotes and some without

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples, extract

I have a list of dictionaries, each dictionary contains:

- First name
- Middle name
- Last name
- Title
- Address
- Email address
- Loyalty program
  For one client. Some of this information may be missing

```
segment = [{'first-name': 'Elsa', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'address': '33 Castle Street, London', 'loyalty-program': 'Gold'}, {'first-name': 'Anna', 'last-name': 'Frost', 'title': 'Princess', 'loyalty-program': 'Platinum'}, {'first-name': 'Harry', 'middle-name': 'Harold', 'last-name': 'Hare', 'title': 'Mr', 'email-address': 'harry.harold@hare.name', 'loyalty-program': 'Silver'}]
```

For clients who have a physical address, I need to extract a list of tuples. Each tuple represents one client and contains their title, first name, middle name, and last name in that order if defined, and the mailing address.

My code appears to be working.

However, within each tuple, there needs to be single quotation marks around the whole and not individual parts of a clients name. There also needs to be quotation marks around the address. A comma needs to separate the address and the full name.

```
('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London')
```

My code is returning the right information, but the elements of a patients name are separated by commas and single quotation marks

```
def process_clients(segment):

    #Creating a list to contain tuples with client full name and mailing address. 
    updated = []
    #Interacting through each dictionary, which represents each client
    for dic in segment:
        newclient=[]
    #Adding clients with a mailing address
        try:
            add = dic["address"]
        except:
            continue
    #Adding, in order, the "title", "first-name", "middle-name", "last-name" and "address" of each client
        for data in ["title", "first-name", "middle-name", "last-name", "address"]:
            try:
                value = dic[data]
                newclient.append(value)
    #If "title", "first-name", "middle-name" or "last-name" is not present in a clients data, no action is taken
            except:
                pass
    #Additing the tuples with extracted client data to the created list        
        updated.append(tuple(newclient))
    return updated


process_clients(segment)


[('Princess',' Elsa ',' Frost ', '33 Castle Street, London')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to go from:

```
data = ('Princess', ' Elsa ', ' Frost ', '33 Castle Street, London')
```

to

```
data = ('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London')
```

To get rid of the extra white space in `' Elsa '` and `' Frost '`, you can use a list comprehension:

```
data = [word.strip() for word in data]
```

For every `word` in `data`, the above line strips off the white space at the beginning and end, then puts it all in a list.

Now we have:

```
data = ['Princess', 'Elsa', 'Frost', '33 Castle Street, London']
```

To combine the first three elements, use `.join()`:

```
data = (' '.join(data[:-1]), data[-1])
```

`' '.join(data[:-1])` takes all elements except for the last and joins them into one string where each element is separated by `' '`. `data[-1]` is the last element in the list.

So now it's:

```
data = ('Princess Elsa Frost', '33 Castle Street, London')
```